# /usr/bin/make overwritten accidentally

Tags: package-management, data-recovery, make

I am extremely new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I accidentally replaced `/usr/bin/make` with another executable and now I need to fix this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install make`.

Tip: It isn't easy to "accidentally" overwrite files in `/usr/bin` *unless* you are logged in as root. Please try to use `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No issues.
/usr/bin/make is provided by package 'make'
just try

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install make
```

In future, you can find which package provides the binaries u want using
http://packages.ubuntu.com/
and then putting binary name in **Search the contents of packages**